# How to set textblock to checkbox content

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox

Not getting a proper solution on how add a textblock to checkbox content property in XAML.
Issue is that checkbox content is not properly displayed for other languages.
So i need to add a textblock to it and apply texttrimming with "CharacterEllipsis".
Please help with a sample XAML code

I have the other properties defined for our custom checkbox:

```
            <uxCCl:UxCheckBox x:Name="btnShowHide"
                          Height="24"
                          MaxWidth="200"
                          Margin="16,0,0,0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Command="{Binding Path=ShowHideErrorOutCommand}"
                          Foreground="#638EAC"/>
```

So simply doing this won't work:

```
<Checkbox.Content>
<Textblock> <Text></Textblock>
</Checkbox.Content>
```

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Why does this not work? I tried: `<CheckBox><TextBlock Text="Hello World"/></CheckBox>` and it just works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the TextBlock to the CheckBox content like so:

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="text block" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
    </CheckBox.Content>
</CheckBox>
```

EDIT:

1. Edit the custom CheckBox like I suggested above.
2. Add a Dependency Property to the custom CheckBox:

   ```
   public string TextContent
   {
       get { return GetValue(TextContentProperty).ToString(); }
       set { SetValue(TextContentProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty TextContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "TextContent",
       typeof(string),
       typeof(YOURCLASSNAME),
       new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
       );
   ```
3. Add a Binding to the Text property of the TextBlock:

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=TextContent}"></TextBlock>
   ```

Comment: You didn't mention it was a custom CheckBox. If you can modify it you could edit it like I suggested, add a Dependency Property to the custom checkbox and a binding to hook the content up to the Dependency Property.

Answer (score 1):

```
<CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Your simple answer helped me address a similar problem I had in styling the checkbox label.  Have a +1 ;)